# K&R c book exercise 5-10

Tags: c, pointers

This is about writing a reverse polish calculator reading expression from the command line, I write a very simple one specifically for this example case: expr 2 3 4 + *, it does NOT deal with more complex calculation, but it seems not working either:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 100
static int sp = 0;
static int operand[MAXLINE];
int atoi(char *s);
void push(int);
int pop();
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   while(--argc > 0 && *++argv){
      if (**argv >= '0' && **argv <= '9')
         push(atoi(*argv));
      else if (**argv == '+'){
         push(pop() + pop());
      }
      else if (**argv == '*'){
         push(pop() * pop());
      }
   }
   printf("%d\n", pop());
   return 0;
}
/* atoi: it will convert a string of characters to integer  */
int atoi(char *s){
   int value = 0;
   while(*s){
       value = 10 * value + (*s - '0');
       s++;
   }
   return value;
}
void push(int value){
   if (sp > MAXLINE -1)
      printf("the stack is full!\n");
   else{
      operand[sp++] = value;
   }
}
int pop(){
   if (sp > 0)
      return operand[--sp];
   else
      return 0;
}
```

it seems like it does NOT recognize * sign, for +, it works well, it output 9 for 2 3 4 + +, but 7 for 2 3 4 + *, I don't think recognizing * is a magic stuff, but it does NOT work, any help would be really thankful!

Comment: Probably your shell is expanding the star `*` into filenames. Try `./a.out 3 4 '*'`. You could (??) use `x` instead, otherwise

Comment: @user3121023,@pmg, u guys are right, I spend hours on it, and failed to find the reason, now it is resolved...